# Exception when execute update() of an itk::writertype

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, qt, exception, itk

I have an image in an “itk::image::Pointer salida”. I have checked that it has the correct pixelvalues. I want to save the image into a file, but in the last line, it gives me an exception and now I don’t know what to do:

```
// Saving the result into a file
salida = ui.imageframe->imagereader;
writer = itk::ImageFileWriter<ImageType>::New(); 
writer->SetInput( salida ) ; 
writer->SetFileName ( "output.jpeg");
writer->Update();// ---> EXCEPTION!!
```

The exception goes to  xmtx.c  file ( mutex[mutual exclusion] support for VC++), 
It goes to the last line of this part of the code:

```
_RELIABILITY_CONTRACT
void  __CLRCALL_PURE_OR_CDECL _Mtxlock(_Rmtx *_Mtx)
{   /* lock mutex */
#ifdef _M_CEE
System::Threading::Thread::BeginThreadAffinity();
#endif
EnterCriticalSection(_Mtx);
}
```

Does any of you have had the same problem? Any hint for fixing it?

Thanks in advance

Antonio Gómez Barquero

Comment: What kind of exception is thrown? what does its internal message say? (e.g. the `what()` function of `std::exceptions`)

Comment: First exception in 0x7c812aeb in prueba_r01.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: itk:ExceptionObject in the memory ubication 0x7c812aeb
First exception in 0x7c812aeb in prueba_r01.exe: Microsoft C++ exception [rethrow]: itk:ExceptionObject in the memory ubication 0x7c812aeb
First exception in 0x7c812aeb in prueba_r01.exe: Microsoft C++ exception [rethrow]: itk:ExceptionObject in the memory ubication 0x7c812aeb.

Comment: Qt has caught an exception thrown from an event handler. Throwing exceptions from an event handler is not supported in Qt. You must reimplement QApplication::notify() and catch all exceptions there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try catching the exception and see what it contains. I am not familiar with itk but looking at the API, the following should work:

```
try
{
    writer->Update();
}
catch( itk::ExceptionObject& ex )
{
    qDebug() << ex.what();
}
```

This should lead you to the source of the exception.

Comment: Thanks so much, it says the following thing: "itk::ERROR: JPEGImageIO(01234120): JPEG supports unsigned char/int only